# Android TextView with View more option after 3 lines in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

I want to add "View More" functionality after three lines of text. The text contains the description which is more than 10 lines. Like:

[image]

[image]

But the getLineCount method for Textview works fine in Activity, but in Adapter, it does not work properly.

In Adapter, I have used `ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver(); vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {}`

But it gives issue on scroll.

Is there any method to implement this functionality smoothly in Adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I would try with [post](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#post(java.lang.Runnable)) instead of `ViewTreeObserver`. `post` will postpone the specified work until the TextView has finished with it's current [MessageQueue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#post(java.lang.Runnable)).

```
tv.post {
    // This should provide you the correct line count value
    val lines = tv.getLineCount()
    // TODO: Use this value for whatever you need
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, try [doOnLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#post(java.lang.Runnable)) instead, which works similarly to `post` but will perform the specified work only once the `TextView` has been laid out.

Comment: But I have to set textview line count to 2 if the line count is greater than 2.
But if I add code in tv.post {} method, it will not work.

Comment: It may be related to the fact that this is done in a RecyclerView. Where are you performing this logic? Assuming the text is set in `onBindViewHolder`, you'll want to do the line count measurement there too: `tv.setText(text); tv.post { ... }`

Comment: Yes I want to implement in recyclerview adapter